# chef solo用の自前cookbookを更新しても反映されない

Tags: chef

`nodejs` cookbookを自前cookbookで使おうとしているのですが、`include_recipe "nodejs"` や `nodejs_npm "bower" do ... end.run(:install)` などしても、どうも反映されません。

問題を突きとめるために`log`を入れても、出力されません。

`site-cookbooks/my-cookbook/recipes/default.rb`:

```rb
log "debug" do
  message "hello there"
  level :error
end
```

```sh
$ knife solo cook -i path/to/pem hostename
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私の場合、`knife` の設定ファイルがバージョン管理されておらず、ワーキングコピーに `.chef/knife.rb` がなかったことが原因でした。

[こちらの記事](http://qiita.com/DQNEO/items/0ade0c3fa9616d33bfbb)にあるように、 `knife solo init .` することで `site-cookbooks` を読み込ませるのに必要な設定を生成することができました。

```
cookbook_path    ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]
```